# Understanding Semaphores in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, semaphore

I am trying to understand a section of code written in **C#**:

```
static Semaphore _transactionReceived;
static TransactionsSession _transactionsSession;

static void StartTransactionsStream()
{
    WriteNewLine("Starting transactions stream ...");

    _transactionsSession = new TransactionsSession(AccountID);
    _transactionReceived = new Semaphore(0, 100);
    _transactionsSession.DataReceived += OnTransactionReceived;

    _transactionsSession.StartSession();

    bool success = _transactionReceived.WaitOne(10000);

    if (success)
        WriteNewLine("Good news!. Transactions stream is functioning.");
    else
        WriteNewLine("Bad news!. Transactions stream is not functioning.");
}
```

but I am having trouble understanding what is happening in the code cycle in regards to the `Sempahore` class, particularly what the following lines are doing:

```
_transactionReceived = new Semaphore(0, 100);
```

and

```
_transactionReceived.WaitOne(10000)
```

is doing.

I have viewed and (re)viewed `System.Threading.Semaphore` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphore?view=net-6.0), and I see that the contructor *"Initializes a new instance of the Semaphore class, specifying the initial number of entries and the maximum number of concurrent entries."* **But what does it mean when there are `0` entries?**

Additionally, I see that the `WaitOne(int32)` call *"Blocks the current thread until the current WaitHandle receives a signal, using a 32-bit signed integer to specify the time interval in milliseconds."* But again, **what does `WaitOne` that mean in the context of the code cycle?**

Any pointers or general comments about how this is executing would be helpful.
Many thanks!

Comment: Look at which other pieces of code use the same semaphore. Semaphores are used for synchronization and signalling. I expect the DataReceived handler is what signals the semaphore.

Comment: I'm assuming `_transactionsSession.StartSession();` acquires the Semaphore 100 times. Because the Semaphore can be acquired a maximum of 100 times, this means that the `_transactionReceived.WaitOne(10000);` blocks, because there are no free requests for the Semaphore to grant. The transactions stream is "functioning" when it releases the Semaphore once -- this doesn't mean that the operation is complete, just that one 100th of something has finished, most likely

Comment: Helpful answer on explanation of initialCount: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9363524/255259

Answer (score 2):

> But what does it mean when there are 0 entries?

Exactly that; the `Semaphore` currently has no entries out of a maximum of 100.

If you had constructed the `Semaphore` with `new Semaphore(1, 100);`, then there would have been 1 entry, and another 99 remaining.

It would require a `Semaphore.Release()` to have 100 remaining entries.

> what does `WaitOne` that mean in the context of the code cycle?

If the `Semaphore` has available entries i.e. the current number of entries is not 100, then it returns `true` immediately.

Otherwise it blocks the current thread until an entry is available (proabably by another thread calling `Semaphore.Release()`), at which point the method returns `true`.

If you specify a `int millisecondsTimeout`, that's the maximum amount of time the `Semaphore` will block and wait for an entry to be released.

If that timeout is exceeded, the method returns `false`.

Answer (score 2):

## Explanation on semaphores

A `Semaphore` is a synchronization object that allows a **limited degree** of parallelism in a code section.

For sake of simplicity, suppose you are instantiating a fresh new semaphore on a code block (no shared instance, global variable or other evil). Since multiple threads can execute the same piece of code at the same time, the semaphore guarantees only `x` of them can execute the same block at the same time.

Think of a thread as a worker person. Not by coincidence, threads are often called *worker threads*.

> But what does it mean when there are 0 entries?

The semaphore is in a *red* state, so no one can execute a particular code section **until some thread** unlocks the semaphore. You can create a GUI where multiple threads *race* for the same action, but by the press of a button *you* unlock the semaphore and allow one thread to go.

> But again, what does WaitOne that mean in the context of the code cycle?

It means that **one of the following** happens:

- The semaphore is in a *green* state, i.e. has permits. The thread does not wait, the semaphore is decremented, the operation proceeds
- The semaphore is in a *red* state, i.e. has no permits available

  - Either the `WaitOne` waits 10 seconds (10000ms) because no permit was available during that time
  - Or someone else unlocks the semaphore and the thread that invoked `WaitOne` is good to go

## About your code

There must be some other method that releases the semaphore but it is not shown in the example. In fact, you have a *red* semaphore where you wait, but apparently nobody to release it. I believe that one of these two lines hides a `Semaphore.Release` method

```
 _transactionsSession.DataReceived += OnTransactionReceived;

 _transactionsSession.StartSession();
```