# Unexpected behavior using ClientWebSocket SendAsync and ReceiveAsync methods simultaniously in different tasks (.Net Framework)

Tags: c#, .net, websocket, .net-4.5, channel

I have my custom WebSocket client (using [System.Net.WebSockets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets.clientwebsocket?view=netframework-4.5.2) library) that works pretty well. Internally, library has 2 separate Tasks: first task is sending commands to the web socket server, second task is receiving responses from the server. Inside of each task I use "infinite loop" approach (because they works in background) like:

SendTask:

```
// Task that sends command through the web socket and write them to response queue.
// Implementation of responseQueue & commandQueue are below. 
// CommandQueue has some items at the beggining.
while (webSocket.State != WebSocketState.Closed)
{
  var command = await commandQueue.ReadAsync(cts);
  await webSocket.SendAsync(bytesToSend, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
  //in order to log command sent, push it into response queue.
  responseQueue.Push(command);
}
```

ReceiveTask:

```
//Task that receive responses from the same web socket and push them into response queue as well.

//these variables needs for a multipacket responses
int dataPerPacket = 8 * 1024; //8192
StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
var buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[dataPerPacket]);

while (webSocket.State != WebSocketState.Closed)
{
  var receiveResult = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, recCts);

  // receive message
  strBuilder.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer.Array, buffer.Offset, receiveResult.Count));
  //keep doing until end of message
  while (!receiveResult.EndOfMessage)
  {
      receiveResult = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, recCts);
      strBuilder.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer.Array, buffer.Offset, receiveResult.Count));
  }

  responseQueue.Push(strBuilder.ToString());
  strBuilder.Clear();
}
```

I simplicated my code, but nothing valuable didn't lose. The websocket is just open echo server on the internet.

So, for the command and response queues I am using [Channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/channels) approach and have implemented my own custom class (because I am on .NET Framework 4.5.2) .The intension of this class is to be able to produce (or write) data to the **responseQueue** in the **SendTask** and consume (or read) data from the **responseQueue** in the **ReceiveTask** efficiently, that is, without blocking (and avoid CPU consuming due to infinite loops).

Implementation of Channel:

```
public class Channel
{
        private ConcurrentQueue<string> _queue;
        private SemaphoreSlim _flag;

        public Channel()
        {
            _queue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
            _flag = new SemaphoreSlim(0);
        }
        
        public async Task<string> ReadAsync(CancellationToken readCancelToken)
        {
            await _flag.WaitAsync(readCancelToken);
            if (readCancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                return default;
            }

            if (_queue.TryDequeue(out item))
            {
                return item;
            }

            return default;
        }

        public void Push(string item)
        {
            _queue.Enqueue(item);
            _flag.Release();
        }
    }
```

But, for some unclear reason I have an unexpected behavior when it works. I expect that order of pushing into **responseQueue** will be as the following:

```
command 1, command 2, response 1, command 3, response 2,...
```

that is, async behaviour. While the succeeding **SendAsync** is executing, we are receiving response and push the response in the queue as well. But in fact I am getting the following order:

```
command 1, command 2,.....command 100, response 1, response 2, ....
```

So my question why? For what reason? How can I achieve this?

I'm sure that the reason is not due to Channel's implementation.

What I have done to figure out:

1. If I add some time delay into SendTask (at least `await Task.Delay(1)`) I am getting the order that is expected, that is async behaviour.
2. I use Stopwatch class to measure elapsed time for calling **SendAsync** and it showed me 0 millisecond. It's strange output, but I don't know how to explain this behaviour.
3. Take a look at the source WebSocketClient code to make sure that [**SendAsync**](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/7a11276c97ffc20764693dab68b070d385a45769/src/libraries/System.Net.WebSockets/src/System/Net/WebSockets/ManagedWebSocket.cs#L252) should take some time (in my understanding).

Comment: I suspect the problem isn't with web sockets at all, but rather due to the fact that [`await` implicitly uses `TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/dont-block-in-asynchronous-code.html), as I describe on my blog. I recommend replacing all your websocket code with `await Task.Delay(15)`, and if that still reproduces the issue, post a complete, minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you informed, the problem is:

In your ReceiveTask, there is no command to `Enter` in the semaphore only to `Release`. In order to use a semaphore, all tasks have to request to enter and inform the release.

It works when you do `await Task.Delay(1)` because it gives time to `ReceiveTask` to `Release`.

Here is an example simulating the network `SendAsync` and `ReceiveAsync` operations:

```
using System.Text;

class q77091244
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Channel commandQueue = new Channel("command");       
        Channel responseQueue = new Channel();  

        // SendTask
        Task SendTask = Task.Run(async () => 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SendTask started...");
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                CancellationToken cts = new CancellationToken();
                Console.WriteLine("SendTask Waiting");
                var command = await responseQueue.ReadAsync(cts);
                Console.WriteLine("SendTask Sending");
                await Task.Delay(100); //simulates await webSocket.SendAsync...
                //in order to log command sent, push it into response queue.
                Console.WriteLine("SendTask Push");
                responseQueue.Push(command);
            }
        });

        Task ReceiveTask = Task.Run(async () => 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ReceiveTask started...");
            StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("item x");

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                CancellationToken cts = new CancellationToken();
                Console.WriteLine("ReceiveTask Waiting");
                await responseQueue.WaitAsync(cts);                
                // receive message
                strBuilder.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length));
                Console.WriteLine("ReceiveTask Receiving");
                await Task.Delay(150); //simultates await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, recCts);
                Console.WriteLine("ReceiveTask Push");
                responseQueue.Push(strBuilder.ToString());
                strBuilder.Clear();
            }
        });

        Thread.Sleep(10000);

    }
}
```

The Channel is the same, but initializes `SemaphoreSlim` with 1 to start in a green state ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70465201/1139847)) and `WaitAsync` without `Dequeue` operation:

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

public class Channel
{
        private ConcurrentQueue<string> _queue;
        private SemaphoreSlim _flag;

        public Channel()
        {
            _queue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
            _flag = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
        }
        
        public async Task WaitAsync(CancellationToken readCancelToken)
        {
            await _flag.WaitAsync(readCancelToken);
        }

        public async Task<string> ReadAsync(CancellationToken readCancelToken)
        {          
            await _flag.WaitAsync(readCancelToken);
            if (readCancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                return default;
            }

            string item;
            if (_queue.TryDequeue(out item))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("dequed " + item);
                return item;
            }

            return default;
        }

        public void Push(string item)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("enqueue " + item);
            _queue.Enqueue(item);
            _flag.Release();
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
SendTask started...
SendTask Waiting
ReceiveTask started...
SendTask Sending
ReceiveTask Waiting
SendTask Push
enqueue 
SendTask Waiting
ReceiveTask Receiving
ReceiveTask Push
enqueue item x
ReceiveTask Waiting
dequed
SendTask Sending
SendTask Push
enqueue 
SendTask Waiting
ReceiveTask Receiving
ReceiveTask Push
enqueue item x
ReceiveTask Waiting
dequed item x
SendTask Sending
SendTask Push
enqueue item x
SendTask Waiting
ReceiveTask Receiving
ReceiveTask Push
enqueue item x
ReceiveTask Waiting
dequed
SendTask Sending
SendTask Push
enqueue
```

Comment: Thank you for dive into this. I have some doubts according your response: 1)  "all tasks have to request to enter and inform the release." - I'm not sure it is correct statement, each task being working with one shared syncronization resourse have not to request and then release inside of its body. One task can request (that is, decrease the intenal counter), anoter one can release (that is, increase the counter), but maybe I didn't get you and we are on the same

Comment: 2)I have checked your code, adding `await responseQueue.WaitAsync(cts);` doesn't change any, and after commenting out this block behavious remains the same. Also, my code works with 2 different queues, they  have the different semaphores. The intension of setting `SemaphoreSlim`  to 0 is that we can't read from the queue until it is empty, once it contains any (counter will increase), we can read it (counter decrease).

Comment: I guess maybe the problem is due to .NET web-Socket can't perform SendAsync & ReceiveAsync in [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets.clientwebsocket?view=netframework-4.5.2#remarks) parallel. And because of this, I observe  all command being sent(socket is blocked by SendTask and only sends all command) first, and after all responses is receives.